# Use variable when checking for number of digits Regex in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to check the following with `4` being the variable.

```
'1212'.match(/\d{4}/)
```

I know I can use `'1212'.match(new RegExp(jamie))` to pass a variable into a regex, but then I don't know how to check for digits `\d` side of things.

Comment: `RegExp()` expects a string (or a regex pattern). So...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a string with proper escaping and than using RegExp constructor you can build regex

```js
let temp = 4
let reg = `\\d\{${temp}\}`
let regex = new RegExp(reg)

console.log('1212'.match(regex))
```